# 6th edition WHF vampire counts - blood dragon

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

can someone please explain how this rule works
"Blood Dragon: "+2 to weapon skill. Lords and Counts automatically wear full plate armour (+4 armour save) but generate one less power dice than their magic level in their magic phase, can generate dispell dice as normal.

the part im stuck on is the "generate one less power dice than their magic level"  does this mean a level 4 wizard would generate 3 power dice total for the magic phase?  and a level 3 wizard gets 2 dice and a level 2 wizard gets 1 dice?  or do you still roll 2 dice to generate winds of magic?